# Why does the order matter unlike React here?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
const app = express();
app.use('/auth',userRouter);
app.use(express.json());
```

For literally 2 hours I was stuck with this piece of code right above just because I was writing it for the first time and I knew React earlier where order didn't matter. The solution to the bug in this code was just this:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/auth',userRouter);
```

Now I want to know, in programming terms, why does this order matter this much that my code failed again and again?

I also tried this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());     
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

because I thought `express.json()` had some issue.

Comment: Because in your first version the body is parsed _after_ you try to read it. See e.g. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Yes, order in express certainly matters, and for good reason.  It would be very tricky for example to implement say a 404 page if that middleware wasn't the last.  `useRouter` in your example obviously is using the parsed json, so makes sense that it gets parsed before you try and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Because it`s express framework the way it works the order of middleware function matters and here express.json() is very important because it is responsible for parsing incoming requests with JSON payloads. It extracts the JSON data from the request body and adds it to the request.body. So when you were calling route before express.json() node wasn't parsing request before it hit route middleware and it was empty or undefined.